# VTK- missing semicolon error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vtk, gdcm

I am building VtkGdcm c# wrappers on visual studio 2010. At the following line i got the possibly missing semicolon error. Its header file.

```
vtkStringArray.h
VTK_NEWINSTANCE vtkArrayIterator * NewIterator() ;
```

Any help will be appreciated.